# Cleartext submission of password under login page in MVC c# appliction

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller

User enter credentials in Login page and submit to server the data this data is expose and it can be intercepted attacker -QA team rise the security issue with burb suite.

Comment: May be just use HTTPS?

Comment: it already run https.

Comment: So, it means that hacker can't intercept the data unless he compromises SSL connection.